# Octave error: 'dfs' undefined near line 1 column 1

Tags: octave

how i could run SDF command in octave when i get this error:

[image]

so i have seen this GitHub related project ([octave-networks-toolbox](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox)) and into is there was [SDF](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox/blob/master/DFS.m), so i tried to install it by this command:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo aptitude install octave-networks-toolbox
[sudo] password for so: 
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "octave-networks-toolbox"
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: github hosted files are not automatically available with aptitude / apt - download the files and place them where octave will find them --- I'd expect that to be a preferences / configuration option / setting in octave.

Comment: Did you read the [installation section of the Readme](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox/blob/master/README)? If so, what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `octave-networks-toolbox` package [in the Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=octave-networks-toolbox), so you can't install it using APT.

The [`octave-networks-toolbox` project](https://github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox) is a set of m-files.
So you need to download it, extract and run from Octave:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://codeload.github.com/aeolianine/octave-networks-toolbox/zip/master -O octave-networks-toolbox-master.zip
unzip octave-networks-toolbox-master.zip
cd octave-networks-toolbox-master

octave testAllFunctions.m
```

As for any other MATLAB/Octave code, you can add it to the `path` variable with `addpath`.

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert, i have tried but i get this error:`error: 'octave' undefined near line 1 column 1`

Comment: It seems that you need to read more about Octave and [how to use it](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Running-Octave.html#Running-Octave).